# python 3.x, `type` itself derives from `object`, and `object` derives from `type`

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop

I'm currently learning python OOP model and have been told

> `type` itself derives from `object`, and `object` derives from `type`

I understand that `object` is the default superclass of every class in python 3.x, and `type` class is used to created classes (i.e. class object). `object` and `type` together (somehow) forms the bases of python OOP, but I am still confused as ever about the statement above.

Could someone provide a detailed explanation on the relationship between `object` and `type`, and the roles they play in python OOP. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are metaclasses in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-are-metaclasses-in-python)

Comment: Just because this question has an answer that relates to metaclasses, that does not mean that this question is a duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We need to distinguish subclassing from instantiation. The exact rules can vary with the language, but in Python 3.x--

All classes are *subclasses* of `object` (well, except for `object` itself). `object` is the root of the class hierarchy.

The `type` class is a *subclass* of `object`.

All objects are *instances* of a class.

Classes are themselves objects. (This is not true in every language.)

Class objects, being objects, are instances of a class--class objects are instances of the class `type` (the default metaclass).

Yes, `type` is a class and an object, and it is an *instance* of `type`. `type` has class `type`.

Yes, `object` is a class and an object, and it is an *instance* of `type`. `object` has class `type`.

You can see the class of an object by using `.__class__` or `type()` on it.
You can see the superclasses of a class by using `.__mro__` (method resolution order) on it.

```
>>> type(object)
<class 'type'>
>>> type(type)
<class 'type'>
>>> object.__mro__
(<class 'object'>,)
>>> type.__mro__
(<class 'type'>, <class 'object'>)
```