# Implementing python data model hierarchy

Tags: python-3.x, oop

I've consulted [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52771713/python-3-x-type-itself-derives-from-object-and-object-derives-from-type) but confused how to move forward with these. I provide a brief recap before I ask my question.

**Brief recap**

1 - Everything in python is an instance of a class. This can be confirmed with using

```
x.__class__
```

where x can be anything!

2 - Every class is subclass of "object". This can be confirmed with

```
x.__class__.__mro__
```

where x can be anything!

3 - Every class itself (refer to point 1) is instance of a class called "type". This can be confirmed by

```
x.__class__.__class__
```

where x can be anything!

**My Question**

How can you implement such a logic?!

1- "type" itself is a class, so point 3 alone is confusing! "type", as a class, is an instance of itself!

```
type.__class__.__class__ == type
```

2- point 3 together with point 2 is also confusing! When you want to implement "type", you need "object" to be implemented to derive from it! But in order to have "object" as an instance, you need "type" to be implemented!

How such a thing possible to practically implement?!

```
object.__class__.__mro__[-1] == object
```

Comment: It's possible to implement it for example like this: https://github.com/python/cpython, or more specifically, like this: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/typeobject.c

Comment: Thanks @mkrieger1 . So since I don't know C, I tried to find the python implementation. I referred to [this](https://www.pypy.org/); but couldn't find the github repo and specifically where this is implemented. 

If you kindly help me find it, I would read it and answer it here for others to refer to it later.

Comment: You can't implement it in Python, that's exactly the issue, it's a hack written in C. Which makes sense after all

Comment: Thanks @Bharel . But then how does [PyPy](https://www.pypy.org/) implement it?! I couldn't find the github repo! nor would I know where to find it!

Comment: The reason you can't find a GitHub is because they use a [gitlab](https://foss.heptapod.net/pypy/pypy/-/blob/branch/default/pypy/objspace/std/typeobject.py). I do not know how the JIT in pypy works and what is the end output, but that's the type object. Do keep in mind that `__class__` is a descriptor, meaning it's just a regular function that can return whatever it wants, in this case the `tp_type` pointer IIRC.